# Dart Language and XML package: reading nodes (text contents)

Tags: xml, dart, dart-async

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF8'?>
<root>
    <row filter="FILTER STRING"> // THIS IS THE FIRST "ROW"
        <id>100</id>
        <name>Some nome here</name>
        <text>TEXT CONTENT HERE</text>
    </row>
    <row filter="FILTER STRING"> // THIS IS THE SECOND "ROW"
        <id>101</id>
        <name>Some nome here</name>
        <text>TEXT CONTENT HERE</text>
    </row>
</root>
```

*I'll have lots of rows nodes in just one XML file and I cannot change this structure.*

**So, with XML package, how should I proceed in order to be able to get the text content from specific nodes?**

For example, I would like to get the text from the node called "name" from the SECOND ROW.

**EDIT:**

So far:

```dart
void main() {
    _readFile("test_UTF8.xml").then((xmlContent) {
        var parsedXml = parse(xmlContent);
            parsedXml.findAllElements("row").forEach((row) {
                // EACH "ROW" NODE WILL BE ITERATED HERE.
                // READ "ROW" CHILDREN NODES HERE.
                // FOR EXAMPLE: GET "NAME"'S TEXT CONTENT.
            });
    });
}

Future _readFile(String filename) {
    var completer = new Completer();
    new File(filename).readAsString().then((String xmlContent) {
        completer.complete(xmlContent);
    });
    return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I edited the question with what I have now. I've tried "findElements", but it returns a List of XmlElements, and I want to be precise (something like getElementById).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need a `Completer` here

```dart
Future _readFile(String filename) {
  // a return here achieves the same in most cases
  return new File(filename).readAsString();
  // because this makes this method so short it doen't make much sense to 
  // even create a method for this
}
```

I haven't actually tried this code but according to the `README.md` of the package it should work like this:

```dart
void main() {
  new File("test_UTF8.xml").readAsString()
  .then((xmlContent) {
    var parsedXml = parse(xmlContent);
    return parsedXml.findElements("root")
        .first.findElements("row").toList()[1]
            .findElements('name').first.text; // <= modified
  })
  .then((text) {
    print(text);
  }); 
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I find that documentation lacking of simple examples, like this one in my question. ERROR: Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: Class 'MappedIterable' has no instance getter 'text'.

Comment: Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: Bad state: No element

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait for it.

Comment: I just copied the code and run it: `Some nome here`. (It took a while because `pub upgrade` took so long).

Comment: My bad. I didn't change the source to test and look for "name". It is working fine. Thanks!